# Correlation of error terms in time-series model

Tags: error-handling, statistics, time-series, correlation

I am reading this statistics book where they have mentioned that the attached top plot has no correlation between adjacent residuals. Whereas, the bottom most has correlation with p-0.9. Can anybody please provide some direction as to how to analyze this? Thank you very much for your time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Correlated errors mean that the lag 1 correlation is p. That is, Cor(Yi, Yi-1) = p. This can be modelled using Yi = mu + p epsiloni-1 + epsiloni where epsiloni ~ N(0, 1) for all i. We can verify that the correlation between adjacent data points is p: Cov(Yi, Yi-1) = Cov(p epsiloni-1 + epsiloni, p epsiloni-2 + epsiloni-1) = Cov(p epsiloni-1, epsiloni-1) = p Var(epsiloni-1) = p. Code to demonstrate appears below:

```
set.seed(123)
epsilonX <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
epsilonY <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
epsilonZ <- rnorm(100, 0, 1)
X <- NULL
Y <- NULL
Z <- NULL
Y[1] <- epsilonY[1]
X[1] = epsilonX[1]
Z[1] = epsilonZ[1]
rhoX = 0
rhoY = 0.5
rhoZ = 0.9
for (i in 2:100) {
  Y[i] <- rhoY * epsilonY[i-1] + epsilonY[i]
  X[i] <- rhoX * epsilonX[i-1] + epsilonX[i]
  Z[i] <- rhoZ * epsilonZ[i-1] + epsilonZ[i]
}
param = par(no.readonly = TRUE)
par(mfrow=c(3,1))
plot(X, type='o', xlab='', ylab='Residual', main=expression(rho*"=0.0"))
abline(0, 0, lty=2)
plot(Y, type='o', xlab='', ylab='Residual', main=expression(rho*"=0.5"))
abline(0, 0, lty=2)
plot(Z, type='o', xlab='', ylab='Residual', main=expression(rho*"=0.9"))
abline(0, 0, lty=2)
#par(param)

acf(X)
acf(Y)
acf(Z)
```

Note from the acf plots that the lag 1 correlation is insignificant for p = 0, higher for p = 0.5 data (~0.3), and still higher for p = 0.9 data (~0.5).